# I want to load another HTML page after a specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have one html page "form1.html" which has an animated image. I want to load another page "form2.html" after 5 seconds. How do I do this?

Comment: Why marked duplicate of a jQuery question while the question title is out of jQuery topics?!

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-page-redirect-using-jquery/25537534#25537534

Comment: ^ Clever way of making your third-page question look like the accepted answer, which has 8800 upvotes.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```html
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = 'form2.html';
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

And for home page add only '/'

```html
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = '/';
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 20):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='form2.html'">
```

Answer (score 17):

use this JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href = 'form2.html';
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript's setTimeout:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'form2.html';}, 5000)">
```

Comment: Please do avoid long inline javascript